# How to define/create a Class property of a Generic Class

Tags: c#, generics

I have model classes (AModel, BModel, ..., ZModel) that can be used in a generic class (`Generic<IModel>`).

```
public class AModel : IModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string specialPropsOfA { get; set; }

    public string DoWorkWithSpecialProps()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException(); // do work with on specialsprops
    }
}

public interface IModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string DoWorkWithSpecialProps();
}

public class Generic<T> where T : IModel
{
    public List<T> UseGeneric(string uid)
    {
        //Doing work with Model.id
        return new List<T>();
    }
}
```

I need go thru A - Z and do the same operation

This is currently how I implemented the solution

```
// Does not comply with DRY
Generic<AModel> AGeneric = new();
var A = AGeneric.UseGeneric("axx");

A.ForEach(a => { var doingWork = a.DoWorkWithSpecialProps(); });

Generic<BModel> BGeneric = new();
var B = BGeneric.UseGeneric("bxx"); // same operation as a

B.ForEach(b => { var doingWork = b.DoWorkWithSpecialProps(); /*Do same work as a*/ });
...
```

How would you implement a class (collection) to contain the generic method to iterate over and not repeat myself?

```
// Would comply with DRY
List<Collection> collections = new()
{
    new()
    {
        Generic = new Generic<AModel>(),  // Error: Generic<AModel> != Generic<IModel>
        uid     = "axx"
    },
    new()
    {
        Generic = new Generic<BModel>(),  // Error: Generic<BModel> != Generic<IModel>
        uid     = "bxx"
    }
};

collections.ForEach(c =>
{
    var X = c.Generic.UseGeneric(c.uid);
    X.ForEach(_ => { var doingWork = x.DoWorkWithSpecialProps(); });
});


public class Collection
{
    public Generic<IModel> Generic { get; set; } // What do I change to allow any Generic method
    public string uid { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried setting `Collection.Generic` to be Type dynamic (I would need to cast var c to `Generic<IModel>`) which only moved the problem.

I have made collection a generic class but that required the `List<Collection<IModel>>` which again only move the problem. I have also made `IGeneric` which is an implementation of the `Generic` class but that would still require `IModel`. What type do I declare `Collection.Generic` to allow me to set it to `Generic<AModel>` or to `Generic<ZModel>`?

Comment: It's not immediately clear why you need separate models (A, B etc.). All models seem to just have an additional string called `specialPropsOfA` for example. Why not just rename that `specialPropsOfModel` and add that to the interface?

Comment: It's also not clear what you're trying to achieve with `Generic<T>` class.

Comment: Models represent database tables. Let's say we have PersonModel which has hight, age, name, occupation as other props too. And other called PetModel which has name, age, weight. Each model has similar structures like id, name, etc. Which can be added to Imodel but not every prop can. like occupation. the Generic<Imodel> class is used to connect and query the database it has other methods like SortByAge<Imodel>() or GetAnyOlderThen<Imodel>(int age). It takes the personmodel or Petmodel (structure of the table) and returns a list of it's respective model. Hope this clarifes any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I came up with and currently using was to make a generic class and call each Model with it.

```
public void WorkEachModel<T>(string uid) Where T : IModel
{
    var GenericFunc = new Generic<T>()
    var A = GenericFunc.UseGeneric(uid);
    A.ForEach(a => { var doingWork = a.DoWorkWithSpecialProps(); });
}
```

And instead of creating a "List<collection>" and looping you would call it with each model.

```
WorkEachModel<AModel>("axx");
WorkEachModel<BModel>("bxx");
...
WorkEachModel<ZModel>("zxx");
```

One major limitation is it's not a list so you cannot push or pop Models. For Example, I don't want to use XModel so I pop (or not include it at the start) it from the List and then run thru the loop which will go thru A-Z and exclude X. (But you can have an if statement checking if you want to run X before executing WorkEachModel<XModel>("Xxx")).
Anyways the issue was with DRY and this solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base abstract class
this is my architect
interface :

```
public interface IModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }

    public string DoWorkWithSpecialProps();
}
```

Model de base

```
public abstract class ModelBase : IModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }    

    public string DoWorkWithSpecialProps()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

AModel

```
public class AModel : ModelBase
{    
    public string specialPropsOfA { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: would I set Collection.Generic Type to Generic<ModelBase>? Forgot to mention that AModel would implement DoWorkWithSpecialProp as it is unique with each Model class But that's not an issue Amodel can override it. If I set Collection.Generic Type to Generic<ModelBase> its still a convert type error just now with the abstract class